# how to overload unary / operator?

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to overload unary /(division) operator. But it causes error. However, when I try to overload +,-,* operators, it works fine. Problem causes oly for / operator. My code is as follows:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Box
{

     int x,y;
  public:
       void GetData(int a,int b)
        {
              x=a;y=b;
        }
       void Display()
       {
          cout<<x<<" "<<y;  
       }
      void operator /();
};

void Box::operator /()
{

    x/=2;
    y/=2;
}

int main()
{
     Box b;
     b.GetData(10,20);
    // I am getting error in the following line.
     /b;
     b.Display();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no unary / operator to overload. As an aside, please don't do this. +, -, and / should not modify the operand and should return a new object.

Comment: `operator/()` isn't a unary operator!

Comment: The operators that exists is what you have, you can't change the semantic meaning on an operator (like turning a binary-only operator into a unary one).

Comment: I know I'm late and you probably already know this, but please don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, nor `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as the unary `/` operator. The `/` operator takes two operands.

Note that just because two operators use the same symbol, doesn't mean they represent the same operation. Binary (as in an arity of 2) `-` is subtraction, while unary `-` is negation. Binary `*` is multiplication, while unary `*` is indirection. So while binary `/` is division, unary `/` is meaningless.

Comment: That means I can not overload / operator.Is it?

Comment: @ShahedAdnan You can overload the binary `/` operator, but there is no unary `/` operator to overload, so no.